# Is it possible to use react-native-web to create PWA?

Tags: react-native, progressive-web-apps, react-native-web

We are creating a web site which we want to use RN-web. (it's back port from RN app)

We'd like keep the possibility of converting to PWA later, wonder if it's possible to convert RN-web to PWA?

Answer (score 1):

If you created your application with the `expo-cli`, now it's super easy to do it.

> Expo web projects generate PWA assets and manifest by default, you only need to enable offline web support to get a full PWA.

You can follow the documentation https://docs.expo.io/guides/progressive-web-apps/

And enable service workers on your react native app https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/master/enabling-web-service-workers.md